# Как скопировать выделенный текст в javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет! 
Занимаюсь созданием курса, в котором пользователь может выделить кусок текста и сделать заметку.
В общем суть такая:

1. Пользователь выделил кусок текста.
2. Нажимает на кнопку напр. "Сохранить".
3. Текст сохраняется в новом div и отправляется в другую HTML страницу.

Вопрос, как при помощи javascript можно реализовать данную идею?

Comment: Уточните, где именно пользователь должен выделять текст - это textarea, input или на какой-то странице. И текст должен сохранится текстом или же html-разметка и должна ли она потом сохраняться?

Comment: Текст находится в html разметке в теге div, а сохранять текстом, так как текст может копироваться обрывками предложений и т.п.

Comment: Тогда следующий вопрос, как вы планируете осуществить отправку данных на другую страницу. Используя серверную часть, то есть отправить на сервер, а при загрузке страницы получить с сервера эти данные. Или хранить локально на компьютере пользователя, например в localStorage, или передать их еще каким-нибудь способом.

Comment: Используя серверную часть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привел пример того, как можно выделить текст и сохранить его в div по нажатию на кнопку "сохранить", отправка идет на сервер через POST запрос.

```js
function getSelectionText() {
  var text = "";
  var activeEl = document.activeElement;
  var activeElTagName = activeEl ? activeEl.tagName.toLowerCase() : null;
  if (
    (activeElTagName == "textarea") || (activeElTagName == "input" &&
      /^(?:text|search|password|tel|url)$/i.test(activeEl.type)) &&
    (typeof activeEl.selectionStart == "number")
  ) {
    text = activeEl.value.slice(activeEl.selectionStart, activeEl.selectionEnd);
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  }
  return text;
}

var saveText = function() {
  var selectionText = getSelectionText();
  document.getElementById("sel").innerHTML = selectionText;
  //пост отправка
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url, true); //url - адрес, на который надо отправить записку.
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    note: selectionText
  }));
}
```

```css
div,
button {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
}

#sel {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fafafa
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Текст предназначенный для выделения</p>
  <p>Текст предназначенный для выделения2</p>
  <p>Текст предназначенный для выделения3</p>
</div>
<div id="sel">Здесь будет текст, который будет выделяться</div>
<button onclick="saveText();">Сохранить</button>
```

А для получения кода используем xhr-request на другой странице

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, false); //здесь url по которому получаем данные
xhr.send();
if (xhr.status != 200) {
    alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );
} else {
    alert( xhr.responseText ); // responseText -- текст ответа.
    //здесь какая-то вставка текста в div, textarea и т.д.
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать ваш вариант.

Comment: Sergey Glazirin, как будет выглядеть код если делать локально?

Comment: Если вместо сервера локально, то вместо `xhr-запроса` используйте `localStorage['note']=selectionText;`, а при загрузке страницы считывайте эти данные и вставляйте их туда, куда вам нужно.